# Android scenario where ondestroy() is called without onpause() or onstop()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

A few days back I was asked to write down scenarios where ondestroy()  is called without onpause() or onstop() being called. Is it possible. If yes please explain.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you try below code, you will find a scenario where `onDestroy()` is indeed getting called while `onPause()` and `onStop()` lifecycle callbacks are skipped.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onPause");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onStop");

    }
```

In other words, if you call `finish()` while creating the Activity in `onCreate()`, the system will invoke `onDestroy()` directly.

Comment: There is another scenerio where onPause is called once before onStop(), and in a worker thread that is not stopped, finish() is called which would skip onPause() and get onDestroy() to be called.

Answer (score 7):

> onPause() and onStop() will not be invoked if finish() is called from
>   within the onCreate() method. This might occur, for example, if you
>   detect an error during onCreate() and call finish() as a result. In
>   such a case, though, any cleanup you expected to be done in onPause()
>   and onStop() will not be executed.
>
> Although onDestroy() is the last callback in the lifecycle of an
>   activity, it is worth mentioning that this callback may not always be
>   called and should not be relied upon to destroy resources. 
>   There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.It is
>   better have the resources created in onStart() and onResume(), and
>   have them destroyed in onStop() and onPause, respectively.

Refrence - https://www.toptal.com/android/interview-questions

Answer (score 3):

This happens when we call finish method to activity
Example:
inside your activity call `this.finish();`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible when we call finish() directly in an activity.
When finish() is called in an activity, onDestroy() is executed and it does following things:

1. Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
2. Close any cursors the activity was managing.
3. Close any open search dialog

Answer (score 0):

When Activity B call From Activity A
then
. A onCreate
. A onStart
. A onResume
. A  onPause
. B onCreate
. B onStart
. B onResume
. A onStop
2. Back Button press
. OnCreate
. OnStart
. OnResume
. OnPause
. OnStop
. OnDestroy
3. onPhoneCall
. onCreate
. OnStart
. OnResume
. OnPause
.  OnStop

4.What happens when you call finish inside onCreate?
-> OnDestroy will call as soon as created

5. Give an example where onPause is called and onStop is not called?
   -> any dialog box or any ads appear on screen of activity